# Get HTTP request command

Tags: javascript, lodash

I have an HTTP request using axios

```
axios.get('http://www.omdbapi.com?s=' + searchText + '&apikey=xxxx')
```

How I can get the same HTTP request but using lodash?

Comment: Using `lodash` for what?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can't. The lodash library has no features for making HTTP requests.

You need a library which can do that. Axios (which I recommend) is popular and available for browsers and Node.js. Browsers have fetch and XMLHttpRequest built-in. Node.js has a built-in module called http.